# Python -Is there any difference between these two ways to input integers into lists?

Tags: python

I've been googling different ways to input integers into lists, and I found these two things.

But, it seems like the output is nearly the same. Are there any differences between these two ways? 
   (like the speed or readability...etc)

```
a = list( map(int,input().split()))

b = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Comment: `map()` is generally considered unpythonic, and doesn't seem all that useful now that we have list comprehensions and generator expressions. Aside from that, I can't think of any noteworthy differences.

Comment: I would think more of `map()` as a short cut but you could argue that in this case the generator expression would deem more appropriate in terms of displaying what you're doing, the latter way is already a fast way comparing it to a for loop, that will be longer...for sure

Comment: What do you mean, *"output is **nearly** the same"*?

Comment: sorry, I meant **totally** the same, not **nearly**